# append string to value list in python dict

Tags: python, dictionary

Trying to learn Python. I have a key in a dict where the value is a list. Is it possible to append a string to all items in the list?

```
value = {
  "mything": ["pizza", "burger", "tacos"]
}

category = "food-"
print (value["mything"])
# prints ['pizza', 'burger', 'tacos']
```

What I want to achieve is this output:

```
print (value["mything"])
# prints ['food-pizza', 'food-burger', 'food-tacos']
```

Comment: Yes: iterate through the list and concatenate to each.  Replace the old string with the new.  Where are you stuck with this?

Comment: `value['mything'] = [category + x for x in value['mything']]`

Answer (score 1):

Since you're new, here's a simple loop to get what you need.

```
for key in iter(value.keys()):
    value[key] = ["food-"+ v for v in value[key]]
```

But, I would prefer this:

```
value['mything'] = ['food-'+v for v in value['mything']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple approach of how this could be done, partly based on your code:

```
value = {
  "mything": ["pizza", "burger", "tacos"]
}

category = "food-"
results = []
for item in value["mything"]:
    results.append(category + item)

print(results)
```

Output:

```
$ python3 example.py
['food-pizza', 'food-burger', 'food-tacos']
```

Answer (score 0):

`print(["food-"+i for i in value["mything"]])`

Comment: Code dumps do not make for good answers. You should explain *how* and *why* this solves their problem. I recommend reading, "[How do I write a good answer?"](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score -1):

You could use list comprehension to prepend the category to all items in the list

```
print ([category+food for food in value["mything"]])
```